# overwrite nodejs built-in javascript libraries

Tags: node.js

we need to update lib\buffer.js file to test out https://github.com/strongloop/node/commit/5c94ae11a20a5192e73239e50e5edbbb33e1dc80

I wonder if there is any way to pass new file or file location when starting node exe or do I have to rebuild node binaries?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

> Node has several modules compiled into the binary. These modules are
>   described in greater detail elsewhere in this documentation.
>
> The core modules are defined in node's source in the lib/ folder.
>
> Core modules are always preferentially loaded if their identifier is
>   passed to `require()`. For instance, `require('http')` will always return
>   the built in HTTP module, *even if there is a file by that name*.

So yes, you must rebuild the binary.